# How do I script out a full database to a series of creation scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I'm looking for a way to script out an entire SQL Server 2015 database to write table creation scripts, stored procedure scripts, triggers, etc etc to a folder so I can set a baseline for a TFS repository solution. Apart from manually exporting each script one by one, is there a way to do a bulk export?

Obviously I'm not talking about data here, I'm talking strictly about exporting creation SQL file scripts to a folder for a single database.

Comment: Seems like a SSDT Schema Compare would work for you here.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - take your pick ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with SQL Server Management Studio.

To open the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard. In Object Explorer, expand Databases, right-click a database, point to Tasks, and then click Generate Scripts. Follow the steps in the wizard to script the database objects. On the Choose Objects page, select the objects to be included in the script.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can generate sql scripts in ssms by following steps:

1. Right Click on the Database
2. Go to task  and then Click on "Generate Scripts..."

[image]

3. follow the wizard steps to create scripts

[image]